# How to ensure that the element in the layout stays the same even when there's a change in orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation

I have a question. I was testing my application on my phone using portrait orientation and the layout turns out perfectly fine. However, when I rotate my screen to landscape, the buttons and EditText goes out of place, therefore I am wondering is there a way to make the elements stay in place regardless of the orientation? Thanks in advance. 
For reference, I am using relative layout for my project.

Comment: Create separate layouts with the same name, e.g., `main.xml`. Put one in the `/res/layout` directory (for portrait) and the other in `/res/layout-land` for landscape - the OS will pick whichever is needed depending on orientation.

Comment: I have created and put the xml file in but the elements are still out of place.

Comment: if you can copy your layout here, would be easy to find out why,

Comment: Hi, I have solved the problem. It turns out it's my mistake. Sorry for the trouble and thanks for the answer.